# Name of the mochawesome report is not saving as expected (even though 'reportFilename' in cypress.json is changed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, cypress, mochawesome

i am using mochawesome for my cypress tests.

**This is my cypress.json file**

```
{
  "viewportWidth": 1440,
  "viewportHeight": 800,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 8000,
  "reporter": "mochawesome",
  "reporterOptions": {
      "reportDir": "cypress/reports/mochawesome-report",
      "reportFilename": "sample",
      "overwrite": false,
      "html": true,
      "json": true  
   },
  "env": {
    "environment": "Stagging"
  },
  "screenshotsFolder": "cypress/reports/mochawesome-report/assets",
}
```

when I ran my tests, the reports are generated with name '**sample.html**' which is expected as I have defined my report title as sample in **cypress.json** file.

now I wanted to have a unique name for each report generated based on the test suite name.

so I have used the **cypress event** '`test:before:run`' and set the `reportFilename` in **cypress.json** to the test suite name before the execution of each test, the sample code is down below

```
Cypress.on("test:before:run", (test, runnable) => {
    console.log(Cypress.config("reporterOptions").reportFilename);
    const suiteTitle = runnable.parent.title;
    Cypress.config({
        "reporterOptions":{
            "reportFilename": suiteTitle
        }
    });
    const reportFileName = Cypress.config("reporterOptions").reportFilename;
    console.log(reportFileName);
});
```

I see the `reportFilename` is successfully changed to Tests suite name in configuration file

[image]

**But my report is still saved as 'sample.html'**
[image]

**Why my report is still saving as sample.html , instead of my test suite name?**

can you someone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue, this requires new enhancement to moachawesome codebase and looking for help

https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome/issues/293